# Using C# to populate a DataGridView with CSV file, and update Access database with results

Tags: c#, database, ms-access, datagridview

I have a C# Windows Forms project that interacts with an Access database (accdb). I have one form that reads the database just fine, and displays it into a DataGridView. I have another form that submits textbox information into the database just as fine.

I have another form (see image below) that allows the user to click a button (button 1) to open a CSV file, using "openFileDialog", and display the selected file's contents in the dataGridView on the form *(example shown below)*.

**MY GOAL: I want a button (button 3), on that same form, to submit the dataGridView's displayed results into the previously mentioned Access database.**

It seems like I have all of the components I need. It feels like I'm not too far off, but there still seems to be something wrong and/or missing in my code. I've been trying to accomplish this for weeks. PLEASE HELP!!!

Here is both, a screen shot of the form, and the full code for the form. ALL help is GREATLY appreciated!

[image]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace csvToGrid
{
    public partial class Import : Form
        {
            public Import()
                {
                    InitializeComponent();
                }
        public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                string delimiter = ",";
                string tablename = "medTable";
                DataSet dataset = new DataSet();
                OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
                openFileDialog1.Filter = "CSV Files (*.csv)|*.csv|All Files (*.*)|*.*";
                openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 1;
                if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                    {
                        if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to import the data from \n " + openFileDialog1.FileName + "?", "Are you sure?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
                            {
                                filename = openFileDialog1.FileName;
                                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filename);
                                string csv = File.ReadAllText(openFileDialog1.FileName);
                                dataset.Tables.Add(tablename);
                                dataset.Tables[tablename].Columns.Add("Prescription");
                                dataset.Tables[tablename].Columns.Add("Customer Name");
                                dataset.Tables[tablename].Columns.Add("Medication");
                                dataset.Tables[tablename].Columns.Add("Quantity");
                                dataset.Tables[tablename].Columns.Add("Date Filled");

                                string allData = sr.ReadToEnd();
                                string[] rows = allData.Split("\r".ToCharArray());

                                foreach (string r in rows)
                                    {
                                        string[] items = r.Split(delimiter.ToCharArray());
                                        dataset.Tables[tablename].Rows.Add(items);
                                    }
                                this.dataGridView1.DataSource = dataset.Tables[0].DefaultView;
                                MessageBox.Show(filename + " was successfully imported. \n Please review all data before sending it to the database.", "Success!", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
                            }
                        else
                            {
                                this.Close();
                            }
                }
            }

        public string filename { get; set; }


        private void openFileDialog1_FileOk(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
            {

            }

        private void Import_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

            }

        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Exit();

        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

            //remove the semicolon, and add brackets below after line
            {   
                //create the connection string
                string connString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Search\\Database.accdb";
                //create the database query
                string query = "SELECT * FROM script_Orders";
                //create an OleDbDataAdapter to execute the query
                OleDbDataAdapter dAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, connString);
                //create a command builder
                OleDbCommandBuilder cBuilder = new OleDbCommandBuilder(dAdapter);
                //create a DataTable to hold the query results
                DataTable dTable = new DataTable();
                //fill the DataTable
                dAdapter.Fill(dTable);
                //the DataGridView
                DataGridView dataGridView1 = new DataGridView();
                //BindingSource to sync DataTable and DataGridView
                BindingSource bSource = new BindingSource();
                //set the BindingSource DataSource
                bSource.DataSource = dTable;
                //set the DataGridView DataSource
                dataGridView1.DataSource = bSource;
                // An update function to get the changes back into the database.
                dAdapter.Update(dTable);
            }

        }
    }
```

[image]

**Examples are more than welcome!**

Comment: this is a very good example of what you want but you have failed to explain what the actual issue / error is that you are having are you getting any errors? if so please state what the error is ..

Comment: Big negative, my friend.
After clicking "button 1" in the form shown above, and successfully importing the CSV file to the dataGridView, There is are no Warnings, Errors or Messages.

Comment: @DJKRAZE
The import is successful with the "\r" in there.
Note the line that reads:

`string delimiter = ",";`

The problem I am having is with the code after:


`public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)`

Comment: Is it safe to assume that all the rows imported from the CSV are going to be inserted into the access table? Or are you updating rows as well?

Comment: @ConradFrix
It is my intention to import ALL rows. Just still trying to figure out how.
:-)

Comment: @ConradFrix

I could have sworn you sent me an example, that doesn't seem to be listed here any longer.

Anyway, I am now getting the error:

**"Additional information: Data type mismatch in criteria expression."**

the INSERT code is as follows:

`var accessCmd = new OleDbCommand(@"INSERT INTO script_Orders (script,cust_Name,drug,qty,fill_Date) VALUES (atPrescription, [atCustomer Name], atMedication, atQuantity, [atDate Filled])", accessCnn);`

"VALUES" are preceded with **at** to represent "at" symbols. My suspicion is the date part of the insert is causing the issue. Any thoughts on it?

Comment: So I temporarily removed the parameter including the date, and I still got the  
**"Additional information: Data type mismatch in criteria expression."** error message.
Something in there isn't allowing the insert. do I have the "addWithValue" arguments wrong? I'll post that code as well.

Comment: ` . . . (@"INSERT INTO script_Orders (script,cust_Name,drug,qty) VALUES (@Prescription, [@Customer Name], @Medication, @Quantity)", accessCnn);

foreach (var row in dataset.Tables["medTable"].Rows)
{
accessCmd.Parameters.Clear();
accessCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("script", @"Prescription");
accessCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("cust_name", @"Customer Name");
accessCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("drug", @"Medication");
accessCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("qty", @"Quantity");
//accessCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("fill_Date", "@Date Filled");
accessCnn.Open();`
 *Abbreviated above & left "date field" out*

Comment: @Geo I restored my answer. Access does not support named parameters so you should go ahead and use `?` as the place holder.

Comment: **"mismatch"**
`var accessCmd = new OleDbCommand(@"INSERT INTO script_Orders (script,cust_Name,drug,qty,fill_Date) VALUES (@Prescription, [@Customer Name], @Medication, @Quantity, [@Date Filled])", accessCnn);
foreach (var row in dataset.Tables["medTable"].Rows)
{
accessCmd.Parameters.Clear();
accessCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Prescription", "script");
accessCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Customer Name", "cust_Name");
accessCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Medication", "drug");
accessCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Quantity", "qty");
accessCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date Filled", "fill_Date");`

Comment: Still getting that pesky **"Additional information: Data type mismatch in criteria expression."** error message.
I made a few changes above.

Comment: @Geo you are providing literal string values. "Fill_date" . You need to use a variable there. eg. `accessCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date Filled", aDateValue)` or `accessCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date Filled", row["SomeColumnName"])`

Comment: @ConradFrix

I have added the following line:,

`accessCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date_Filled", row["fill_Date"]);`

In doing so, I get two errors:

**"Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'object'"**

and

**"The type Import is made of several partial classes in the same file."**

I am getting SUPER FRANTIC for the solution to this!  LOL

Comment: I would be more than happy to send the entire project to anyone, if it means I can get the answer. It seems like it would be so trivial, to pass dataset value to a database. EVERYONE's help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: @geo  I'm happy to try help, but I think we should take this to chat. can you go to this [chatroom](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20520/room-for-conrad-and-geo)

Comment: @Geo in any case I did make an error. I forgot the .Rows in the foreach. It should have been  `foreach(var row in dataset.Tables["medTable"].Rows)`

Comment: I added a screenshot at the end of the original post, to show the errors I get with each specific code I use. Let me know if there is someplace I can send a copy of the project, for your convenience. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: @Conrad
I added the .Rows based on another person's post anyway, so no worries.
@ Everyone
Would anyone care to download the project for me, to help me figure this out? I'd super appreciate it! Let me know, and I'll post it to an online share.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming all you want to do is take the contents of the CSV and insert them into your table you can just loop though your dataset and call an insert command (with a parameterized query of course)

```
var AccessCnn = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Persist Security Info=False;", @"C:\YOURDBNAME.accdb");

using (OleDbConnection accessCnn = new OleDbConnection(AccessCnn))
{


    //Create The Command
    var accessCmd = new OleDbCommand(@"INSERT INTO script_Orders  
                                       (Prescription, [Customer Name], Medication, Quantity, [Date Filled])
                                    VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)", accessCnn);

   foreach(var row in dataset.Tables["medTable"].Rows)
   {
      accessCmd.Parameters.Clear();

      accessCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", row["Prescription"]);
      accessCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", row["Customer Name"]);
      accessCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", row["Medication"]);
      accessCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", row["Quantity"]);
      accessCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", row["Date Filled"]);

      ccessCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
   }


}
```

You will need to move your DataSet to be a class level variable

```
public partial class Import : Form
{
     DataSet dataset;
```

and then later in button1_Click assign it instead of declaring and assigning it

```
string tablename = "medTable";
dataset = new DataSet();
```

Answer (score 2):

The challenge comes from using a dataset object to work with the data while the CSV file is external to the Access database. To resolve this you can programmatically persist updates from the DataGridView to the Access database.

Insert Example

```
DataRow anyRow = DatasetName.ExistingTable.NewRow();
anyRow.FirstName = "Jay";
anyRow.LastName = "Stevens";
ExistingTable.Rows.Add(anyRow);
```

Update Example

```
dsCustomers1.Customers[4].CompanyName = "Wingtip Toys";
dsCustomers1.Customers[4].City = "Buffalo";
```

Delete Example

```
dsCustomers1.Customers.Rows[0].Delete();
```

Hope this helps. Cheers.

Comment: What you typed makes perfect sense.
I guess, then,  my next question would be:
"Do I need to do an **insert** AND an **update** in my code, so the data gets to the database and updates it as well?"
If not, which should I use, and where in my code do I insert it?

Thanks for you response!

Comment: As long as the data is changed before you write it to the database, you only need an insert. Otherwise, you will need an update too. You can put the code in the button3_Click event.

Comment: Would it be safe for me to assume that the data will changed before I write it to the database, by virtue of the fact that I will be importing it from the CSV first?

Comment: Yes, you can make that assumption.

Comment: @Geo, if my answer helped you resolve the question then please mark it as the chosen answer. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at creating an UPDATE command for your Data Adapter.

This Guide below will get you started in understanding Data Adapters better :-

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/33y2221y.aspx

Good Luck!!

Comment: the above answer is for your comment on how to insert and update