# how to manupilate database through data grid

Tags: c#, database, datagrid

guys here is what i have come up with I cant figure out what is the prob that is not allowing me to update the tables in the database

guys I need ur help I need to update my data base through data `grid` using c# as of yet all that I am able to do is that I am able to see the values that are inside the sql server that I put directly.`

```
string sConnectionString = "Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=ScratchCardSystem2;Integrated Security=True;pooling=true";
SqlConnection objConn = new SqlConnection(sConnectionString);
objConn.Open();
string query = "SELECT * FROM store_adj_note_detail_1";
SqlDataAdapter dAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query,objConn);
//dAdapter.SelectCommand= new SqlCommand(query, objConn);
SqlCommandBuilder cBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(dAdapter);
DataTable dTable = new DataTable();
//fill the DataTable
dAdapter.Fill(dTable);
dataGridView1.DataSource = dTable;

dAdapter.Update(dTable);
```

Comment: what row are you wanting to update..? this is the part that you are missing.. also I think you need a DataSet object instead of DataTable

Comment: you cant update your data with that query.

Comment: @DJ Kraze well all of the rows in a data base

Answer (score 0):

```
 OleDbCommandBuilder commandBuilder = new OleDbCommandBuilder(dAdapter);
```

Is missing.
MSDN says:

```
//Without the OleDbCommandBuilder this line would fail.
dAdapter.Update(dTable);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing something that binds your datagridview to your datatable. The trick here is that you need a BindingSource.

Add the following before your '//fille the datatble' line

```
BindingSource bindSrc = new BindingSource();
```

Then change your datasource of your datagridview and add a source to your bindingsource as well, like this:

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = bindSrc;  
bindSrc.DataSource = dTable;
```

EDIT: I forgot to mention a tiny thing: to update, you now have to refer to the datatable that is the source of your bindingSrouce, this is how I did it:

```
dAdapter.Update((DataTable)bindSrc.DataSource);
```

Might be possible just with the regular update(dTable), but if it doesn't, this probably fixes it

Comment: As I can't comment on Daniel's answer due to low rep, i'll do it here;

OleDbCommandBuilder (and anything else with OleDb) is for use with MS Access files. In other words, for communicating with Access databases. In this case he is using a SQL database, and thus has to use SqlCommandBuilder, which he did in a correct manner (As far as I can tell). It's just that you need a bindingsource between your datatable and your datagridview, or any changes that you make won't be picked up by the table.

Comment: you can comment his answer, for his notification message :D

Comment: Nope I can't, need 50 reputation ;) until then, I can only comment on my own answers (or on answers of my own questions)

Comment: @ ward d.s well  when i first created the datagrid i had it binding with the sql table other wise i wouldnt even be able to retreive the values dont u think ?

Comment: You just keep the datagrid bound to the bindingsource and the bindingsource to the datatable at all times. At least that's what I did and it worked like a charm. Keep in mind I declared all of these globally, top of the class. Declaring locally could potentially mess it up.
I'll work on a new response with a proper full-written example now, but here's a link already to what seems like a similar problem:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13571799/using-c-sharp-to-populate-a-datagridview-with-csv-file-and-update-access-databa?rq=1

Comment: Also, I just noticed I'm not supposed to write   
BindingSource bindSrc = new BindingSource();  
but just   
bindSrc = new BindingSource  
strange...

Comment: Ward D.S well i tried that and it didnt worked the data base and data gris is connected and i am able to receice the values from the sqlsrever table. how ever when it comes to u know inserting it the things that i insert they dont get inserted at all

Comment: Have you gotten any errors? I found the try-catch I wrote around the opening and updating very handy on specifying where the problem was. Have you gotten any errors so far? (either with or without try-catching)

Comment: well no i didnt catch any error how ever i still cant get my sql database to be updated.

Answer (score 0):

So this is basically what I used for my own form. On establish connection the connection opens and it fills up my datagridview1 with the data from store_adj_note_detail_1.
<s>Notice I never declare my bindingSource... I don't know the reason either, but I tried declaring it with the rest of them (globally) and locally, both made the code break :/</s>

The declaration of your BindingSource happens on the Design view of your form - just drag it from the toolbox on top of your form and it will show up with an icon like FileDialogs and Menustrips do. I personally only changed the Name property and didn't add any events.

It should give you the overview of everything you need to open a connection, use the bindingsource to link your datagridview and your dataTable, and update your database.

I got this code by editing my own code that I used for an access database, but SQL databases seem to work exactly the same way, just with different entities (sqlDataAdapter and the likes instead of OleDb...).

hope this helps you!

```
public partial class FrmDatabaseConnection : Form
{
    // Connection, Adapter, DataTable, CommandBuilder, Bindingsource and command
    private SqlDataAdapter adap;
    private DataTable dataTable;
    private SqlCommandBuilder commandBuilder;
    private string sqlCommand = "SELECT * FROM store_adj_note_detail_1";
    private SqlConnection conDB = new SqlConnection();

    //To open connection and fill datagridview1
    private void establishConnection()
    {
        try
                {
                    conDB.ConnectionString = "Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=ScratchCardSystem2;Integrated Security=True;pooling=true";
                    conDB.Open();

                    // Set adapter, commandbuilder, datatable and bindingsource
                    adap = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCommand, conDB.ConnectionString);
                    commandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(adap);
                    bindSrc = new BindingSource();
                    dataTable = new DataTable();

                    // Fill it!
                    adap.Fill(dataTable);
                    dataGridView1.DataSource = bindSrc;
                    bindSrc.DataSource = dataTable;


                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Unable to Open database, " + ex.Message,);
                    conDB.Close();
                }

    }

    private bool saveToDatabase()
    {
        try
                {
                    adap.Update((DataTable)bindSrc.DataSource);
            }
        catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Unable to Update database, " + ex.Message);
                    return false;
                }

    }


}
```

Comment: Aah I figured it out. A Bindingsource is an item from the toolbox that I dragged on the form - It appears in the bar under your form, much alike an OpenFileDialog does. That's how I declared it on my form (completely missed that..). I only changed the name on mine, no other properties or events where touched.

Comment: Oke, let me know how it goes!

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that, I wasn't aware that this was a bad example of doing things. Did he explain anything more? (as in, why this is stupid?) I'm really curious now since I used this code as part of my own school project - and the teacher didn't comment on it.

Comment: he says that in big corporations this is kinda like a bomb its in-efficient tardy will greatly increase the maintenance all in all every thing thats agains the very essence of the coding how ever u can use data-grid to get the value or retrieve the values

Comment: he says that in big corporations this is kinda like a bomb its in-efficient tardy will greatly increase the maintenance all in all every thing thats agains the very essence of the coding how ever u can use data-grid to get the value or retrieve the values